# How to start js script from cmd

Tags: javascript, cmd

I need help! I want to start js script from cmd, i used  Cscript.exe, but script does not  start. After I tryed to use jrunscript, but I got error:

```
script error in file C:\AmdocsCRM8.1\EclipseWS\SmartClient\out\Admin\startCRM.js : sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "WScript" is not defined. (C:\AmdocsCRM8.1\EclipseWS\SmartClient\out\Admin\startCRM.js#2) in C:\AmdocsCRM8.1\EclipseWS\SmartClient\out\Admin\startCRM.js at line number 2
```

In script is there object WScript

```
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

My scrip strart java application, and its main task collect class path for java app, and start it.
I created shortcut and start this script double click, but want to statrt it from cmd

Answer (score 2):

install NodeJs https://nodejs.org/en/ and start it

```
node startCRM.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NodeJS framework (https://nodejs.org/) to invoke JS on your machine.  It bundles the JavaScript runner with it and you can use `node` command to run a JS program, or to enter a REPL.

e.g.

```
$ node
>> var a = 2 + 3;
   5
```

You can also use [Chrome Headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for running server side scripts.  Internally it uses Node itself.